# Открытие файла при помощи выбранной или используемой по умолчанию программы

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Решил написать небольшую программку, или скорей плагин для плеера, который будет сканировать папку с музыкой и добавлять в лист воспроизведения проигрывателя файлы с меткой в названии.
Для этих целей прибегнул к библиотекам Qt. QDirIterator прекрасно справился с поиском. Но вот на этапе открытия файла я бесповоротно завяз, что бы не делал, не могу заставить `QDesctopServices` запустить файл. С `ShellExecute` дело обстоит чуть лучше, ассоциированная программа по крайней мере запускается, но при попытке передачи переменной в качестве параметра вылезает ошибка. Вот пример моих изысканий, на которые я вчера угробил весь день:

```
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

vector <QString> testV;

unsigned i = 0;
QDirIterator test("G:/testFacility", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (test.hasNext()) {
    testV.push_back(test.next());
    qDebug() << i << testV[i];
    i++;
}
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(testV[2]));
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(testV[2]));
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///g:/testFacility/test(!!).txt"));
QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(testV[2]);
QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(testV[2].toLower()));
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(testV[2].toLower()));
QDesktopServices::openUrl(testV[2].toLower());
//никакой реакции...
qDebug() << testV[2];

//ShellExecute(0, L"open", QString::toWCharArray(testV[2]), 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
//error: no matching function for call to 'QString::toWCharArray...
                                                   ^
//ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"g:/testFacility/test(!!).txt", 0, 0 , SW_SHOW);
//работает, но мне нужно, чтобы в качестве указателя пути была переменная.
}
```

Собственно, вопрос: как можно открыть файл при помощи определенной программы?  Можно ту, которую операционка использует по умолчанию, вариант с указанием конкретной программы меня тоже более чем устроит. ОС windows если что, хотя кроссплатформенное решение было бы чуть более предпочтительным.

Comment: `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///g:/testFacility/test(!!).txt"));` вот такая версия у меня работает, остальные не проверял

Comment: @ixSci хотелось бы знать тогда, почему у меня нечего не работает. Путь верный, по крайне мере в ShellExecute он проблем не взывает. Однако, как дело доходит до QDesktopServices как бы его не вертел не могу добиться результата. Возможно я, что то упускаю из виду, но перепробовал уже пожалуй все(или почти все) варианты, который сумел найти в интернете. Уже даже антивирус проверил, может он, что то блочит, никаких изменений.

Comment: А если `QUrl` создать на отдельно строке и `isValid()` проверить?

Comment: @ixSci проверил сейчас, говорит, что true.

Comment: Странно, но в коде проблем нет, поэтому проблему нужно искать в Вашей системе. Есть другие системы, на которых можно проверить?

Comment: @ixSci в данный момент нет, но на неделе смогу протестить.

Comment: А что debug говорит по поводу того что оно не работает?

Comment: @LevBazdyrev нечего дельного, "exited with code 0". Как бы все работает, но нечего не работает.

Comment: Меня в некотором роде осенило. Решил проверить, а, что, если запустить тот же код в gui проекте. И о чудо, заработало! После этого проверил проект методом исключения, изначально думал, что с .pro что то не так, однако проблема крылась QApplication, вернее в его отсутствии. После того как прописал `QApplication a(argc, argv)` заработал так как нужно. Не совсем понимаю каким образом они связаны, ведь даже в доках указано, что `In such non-GUI mode, it is often sufficient to instantiate a plain QCoreApplication to avoid unnecessarily initializing resources needed for a graphical user interface.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема крылась в классе QApplication, а вернее в его отсутствии. Уж не знаю каким боком он связан с QDesktopServices, но после его добавления, сервисы заработали.
Вот как выглядит рабочий вариант того же кода:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);//QCoreApplication нужного результата не давал.

vector <QString> testV;

unsigned i = 0;
QDirIterator test("G:/testFacility", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (test.hasNext()) {
    testV.push_back(test.next());
    qDebug() << i << testV[i];
    i++;
}

QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(testV[2]));
return app.exec();
}
```

Пожалуй, стоит упомянуть еще о том, что`QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(testV[i]));`в некоторых ситуациях вызывал сбой с выводом ошибки в консоль: `ShellExecute'g:/testFacility/19 Samurai Blade(!!!!E).mp3' failed (error 2).`. Однако, после уточнения`QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(testV[i]));`подобных проблем не было замечано.